# C++: Array Elements are set to 0

Tags: c++, arrays

I have been using arrays for a while now.

I have a few questions that i need to ask.

Now I know i cant use an array without giving a value its element(s).

For example this would give me an error

```
int fly[5];
cout << fly[4] << endl;
```

And if i print an element that doesn't have a set value it would give an error:

```
int fly[5];
fly[2] = 1;
cout << fly[4] << endl;
```

Now I found if I give 1 element of the array any number in the array intialization. Then the rest of the elements are set to 0.

So this code prints 0

```
int fly[5] = {15};
cout << fly[4] << endl;
```

Why does this happen. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Can't cite the standard on this, but I believe that the remainder of an initializer list defaults to 0 if not specified.  (Also, the examples you presented are not errors, but rather, undefined-ish behavior [the behavior is defined, but the content of the arrays is not].)

Comment: According to the standard, if you have an array initializer, but don't specify some of the elements, the rest will be 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens because the C++ language standard says it should happen. The standard says it should happen because it's sensible behaviour and saves a lot of typing in cases where you want a large array initialized.

Your first couple of examples produce undefined behaviour, in that the value of those array elements can be anything, but they shouldn't "give an error". (A sufficiently clever compiler might issue a warning.)

Comment: IMO compilers **should** generate errors for undefined behavior.

Comment: I wasnt clear on that one. I m using Visual C++ Express. So it prints an error message either to break or continue. That is what i meant by an error.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: That would be nice, but the constructs whose behavior is undefined tend to be those that are difficult, or even impossible, to detect in all cases. For example, `i++ + i++` is easy to detect, but `arr[i]++ + arr[j]++` has undefined behavior only when `i == j`. Compilers are certainly permitted to warn about code whose behavior is undefined, or to reject it if they can *prove* that the behavior is undefined. Enabling optimization will often help the compiler to detect such situations, due to the extra analysis it has to perform.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your first two examples are not guaranteed to give an error. If they do not, they will compile and run with undefined behavior. The last one has well-defined behavior. If you do not specify values for every element of an array, the remainder are initialized with the default value, in this case 0.

Answer (score 0):

When you brace-initialize an array and the initializer is too short, the missing elements are value-initialized. For primitive types such as `int`, this means zero-initialization (i.e. the initial value is zero). For example, you can say `int a[100] = {};` to get an all-zero array. Integers aren't special, though, and this works for default-constructible class types just as well.

Your first two examples constitute undefined behaviour, since you are reading an uninitialized variable.